# Peculiar signature generated by sphinx-autodoc

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-sphinx

I have the following function definition (docstring simplified for this example):

```
def ui(*classes, call_init=False):
    'create a metaclass based on *classes*'
    ...
```

When I create a documentation using sphinx-autodoc (specifically, automodule), it generates the following signature for this function

```
ui(call_init, *classes)
```

Can anyone explain why sphinx-autodoc is getting the signature the wrong way round?  Also, is there a way to get it to include default value of *call_init*?

Comment: The signature works (and I've run the function so I'm sure), it just means that the named parameter is keyword only.

Comment: Err, right, it's only a syntax error in python 2. I'd report this as a bug in Sphinx; it's apparently not aware of this usage in Python 3 and thus re-orders for you.

Comment: Ah, yes. I'd forgotten that python2 doesn't support that syntax. Thanks .

Comment: fyi, seems to be an already-reported bug with a patch available: https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx/issue/828/autodoc-python3-keyword-only-arguments

Comment: Wooble, would you care to repost that as an answer?  Because it is one. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to comments made by Wooble on the question, this is a python 2/python 3 difference. And there's already a bug report with an available patch: https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx/issue/828/autodoc-python3-keyword-only-arguments .

Comment: Note: I turned it into a 'community wiki' as it is really Wooble's answer, not mine (I won't get any undeserved reputation points this way). I just wanted to turn it into an answer (as suggested by Marius) so that it can be accepted. This way the question doesn't linger on as unanswered :-)